# jquery call a function each time a class has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the markup for my navigation:

```
<div class="navigation navigation-fixed-top">
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

And I have this jquery script, which is checking if `href="#home"` has class active to do something and if not to do something else.

This is the code:

```
var isActive = $('a[href="#home"]').hasClass('active');
$(".navigation")
.toggleClass("navigation-fixed-bottom", isActive)
.toggleClass("navigation-fixed-top", !isActive);
```

This is partially working because the `class="active"` is added automatically when I'm going the #about section or I'm clicking on it. It does this without refreshing the page so I need a way to to make this work without refreshing the page.

Any suggestions on how can I do this with jQuery/Javascript ?

**UPDATE: 
this is the name of the plugin [Scrollit.js](https://github.com/cmpolis/scrollIt.js/blob/master/scrollIt.js)
THIS IS THE CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR ADDING THE ACTIVE CLASS ON THE NAVIGATION ELEMENTS:**

```
(function($) {
'use strict';

var pluginName = 'ScrollIt',
    pluginVersion = '1.0.3';

/*
 * OPTIONS
 */
var defaults = {
    upKey: 38,
    downKey: 40,
    easing: 'linear',
    scrollTime: 600,
    activeClass: 'active',
    onPageChange: null,
    topOffset : 0
};

$.scrollIt = function(options) {

    /*
     * DECLARATIONS
     */
    var settings = $.extend(defaults, options),
        active = 0,
        lastIndex = $('[data-scroll-index]:last').attr('data-scroll-index');

    /*
     * METHODS
     */

    /**
     * navigate
     *
     * sets up navigation animation
     */
    var navigate = function(ndx) {
        if(ndx < 0 || ndx > lastIndex) return;

        var targetTop = $('[data-scroll-index=' + ndx + ']').offset().top + settings.topOffset + 1;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: targetTop,
            easing: settings.easing
        }, settings.scrollTime);
    };

    /**
     * doScroll
     *
     * runs navigation() when criteria are met
     */
    var doScroll = function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).closest("[data-scroll-nav]").attr('data-scroll-nav') ||
        $(e.target).closest("[data-scroll-goto]").attr('data-scroll-goto');
        navigate(parseInt(target));
    };

    /**
     * keyNavigation
     *
     * sets up keyboard navigation behavior
     */
    var keyNavigation = function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == settings.upKey && active > 0) {
            navigate(parseInt(active) - 1);
            return false;
        } else if(key == settings.downKey && active < lastIndex) {
            navigate(parseInt(active) + 1);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    /**
     * updateActive
     *
     * sets the currently active item
     */
    var updateActive = function(ndx) {
        if(settings.onPageChange && ndx && (active != ndx)) settings.onPageChange(ndx);

        active = ndx;
        $('[data-scroll-nav]').removeClass(settings.activeClass);
        $('[data-scroll-nav=' + ndx + ']').addClass(settings.activeClass);
    };

    /**
     * watchActive
     *
     * watches currently active item and updates accordingly
     */
    function navPosition() {
    $('[data-scroll-nav]').toggleClass('navigation-fixed-bottom navigation-fixed-top');
    }
    var updateActive = function(ndx, navPosition) {
    var watchActive = function() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        var visible = $('[data-scroll-index]').filter(function(ndx, div) {
            return winTop >= $(div).offset().top + settings.topOffset &&
            winTop < $(div).offset().top + (settings.topOffset) + $(div).outerHeight()
        });
        var newActive = visible.first().attr('data-scroll-index');
        updateActive(newActive);
    };

    /*
     * runs methods
     */
    $(window).on('scroll',watchActive).on('scroll');

    $(window).on('keydown', keyNavigation);

    $('body').on('click','[data-scroll-nav], [data-scroll-goto]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        doScroll(e);
    });

};
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: You shouldn't trigger on the class value change. You should tie into the function that does so.

Comment: @JasonP, I don't want to listen just on click because the class is added also when I scroll down to that specific section...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: @isherwood I don't think I get exactly what are you trying to say, can you give me short example ?

Comment: Not without seeing what code adds/removes that class. The point is to extend that function or use a callback on it.

Comment: if you use a plugin to add `"active"` class, post the name (of plugin)... if you made it yourself, the best way is the @isherwood's way, follow his suggestion. :D

Comment: Indeed. As @isherwood said, you should simply include the code to toggle those classes for navigation inside whatever function or functions alter the active class of the home link. If your listener for that link is a general listener for all links in your menu, then it simply needs logic to check if the link just activated is indeed the home link, and toggle classes accordingly.

Comment: Is a `jQuery` only solution good enough? Meaning it will only work if they call `$.addClass/removeClass/toggleClass`.

Comment: I've edited the question with the name of the plugin and the  code responsible for `active` class

Comment: Nice. I not post a answer because I'm pretty sure that @isherwood posts it. :D

Comment: May be you can use `location.hash` value instead of `.active` class? In this case, you could use `$(window).on('hashchange', ...)` and then look at `location.hash`. Are `location.hash` changes when `.active` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[data-scroll-nav]').removeClass(settings.activeClass)
    .toggleClass('navigation-fixed-bottom navigation-fixed-top');
```

and/or

```
$('[data-scroll-nav=' + ndx + ']').addClass(settings.activeClass)
    .toggleClass('navigation-fixed-bottom navigation-fixed-top');
```

If you wanted to keep the original code cleaner, you could do a callback:

```
function myCallBackFunction() {
    $('[data-scroll-nav]').toggleClass('navigation-fixed-bottom navigation-fixed-top');
}
var updateActive = function(ndx, myCallbackFunction) {..}
```

Comment: Syntax fixed for `toggleClass`.

Comment: I've added the callback function from your example inside scrollIt.js file but nothing happens. I've updated my question also with your callback code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What I want  is to check if an `a` element with `href="#home"` has an active class and if so  to make the main div class look like this   `<div class="navigation navigation-fixed-bottom"> and if not to switch to the default "fixed-top"

Answer (score 0):

use jquery on to bind handlers to events you want to respond
`$("a.active").on('click',function(){});`

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. - https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: And this doesn't really answer the question anyway. There isn't necessarily a click event.

Comment: @isherwood click was just a sample , you can bind to the required event.

Comment: I believe that OP use a plugin to add active class on scroll, and 
I'm pretty sure that this plugin has a callback function. You not need to add an event handler.